Formal or informal construction synonyms
Are there any formal or informal synonyms for this construction?
I know all the tricks of the trade, so l am the person in charge here.

OP has asked

Are there any formal or informal synonyms for this construction?
I know all the tricks of the trade, so l am the person in charge here.

My answer
I know the ropes, so I'm the one running the show here.

Yes, good for informality.
